# Select solc version

Tags: solc, docker

I am exploring the best way to switch solc versions on Ubuntu and I looked at the Docker solution. The Docker --help command is of no help, it does not show an option for listing possible solc versions on Docker.

`$ docker run ethereum/solc:stable --help`

The --version command only shows current version.

```
$ docker run ethereum/solc:stable --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.8.19+commit.7dd6d404.Linux.g++
```

Any idea how to list all possible solc versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a specific version use the container tag. For example to run 0.5.4

```
$ docker run ethereum/solc:0.5.4 --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.5.4+commit.9549d8ff.Linux.g++
```

And to run 0.8.17

```
$ docker run ethereum/solc:0.8.17 --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.8.17+commit.8df45f5f.Linux.g++
```